# Change the database in a Spring web app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have created a web app with Spring on the basis of [Maven archetype for spring web app by kolorobot on GitHub](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype)

this archetype. Since I have not been developing with spring for several months, I need some help. This web app is using a HSQL db. I want to change the db, but i am not sure where to do it. Maybe somebody with more experience can help? This is the content of my persitence.properties file:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
dataSource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test
dataSource.username=sa
dataSource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

In my web app there are already several config classes, that come along with the parent archetype.

This is my JPAConfig:

```
package org.stimpy.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurer;

import org.stimpy.Application;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
class JpaConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

@Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
private String driver;
@Value("${dataSource.url}")
private String url;
@Value("${dataSource.username}")
private String username;
@Value("${dataSource.password}")
private String password;
@Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
private String dialect;
@Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
private String hbm2ddlAuto;

@Bean
public DataSource configureDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.stimpy");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}
```

}

I know Spring is very configurable, but at the minute I am lost.

Update:
When I change the persitence properties  to:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
dataSource.username=sa
dataSource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

the maven package command fails. And several tests are failing. In the error output it said:
Table ACCOUNT was not found. Do I have to create the tables manually or does Spring do the job?

Comment: What happened exactly when you changed your database in the quoted `persitence.properties`?

Comment: those are the properties that need to be changed, and what happened when changing them ,could you post error message/problem? also what is the new database, Oracle, MySql etc

Comment: I am trying to use h2 database like user geoand suggestest. But now 7 of 9 tests are failing. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I changed the properties to:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mywebbapp
dataSource.username=root
dataSource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mywebbapp
```

And then created a table named 'mywebabapp' in my local mysql database.

Now i am going to setup multiple environments (test, prod, dev). To let the tests run against the embedded H2-db like user Bobby Zohdy suggeseted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you want to change the database to H2, then you only need the following changes (assuming of course you have added the H2 dependencies to the project):

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to use the in-memory database why not use spring embedded database like :

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

or

```
EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.type(H2).script("schema.sql").script("test-data.sql").build();
// do stuff against the db (EmbeddedDatabase extends javax.sql.DataSource)
db.shutdown()
```

and if you have multiple environments, you can use spring profile  http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

Comment: I want to use a persistent database like mySQL. But don`t know how to change it to that.

Comment: are you want to change it across environments {"dev","int","prod"} or want to change it permanently?, if want to change it cross ENV use spring profiles, also to make it easier check Spring Data project

Comment: Hey Bobo Zohdy i got just one persistence.properties file. Can you tell me how to add another. I understood @Profile, but how to flip the properties file according to active profile?

Comment: ok then you can use org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and set its properties with context place holder which could be selected by spring profile.